# Нормальные формы БД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Добрый день! Прошу оценить мое понимание темы.

1 форма : в таблицах отсутствуют столбцы такие, что они состоят из избыточных, повторяющихся(из строки в строку) данных. 
Как привести: разделить такие столбцы на несколько(по количеству повторяющихся записей)

2 форма : 1я форма + в таблицах есть столбцы такие, что они не являются ключами, но имеют функциональную зависимость с остальными столбцами(задав значение таких столбцов, получим остальные).
Как привести: разделить таблицу на несколько(по количеству потенциальных ключей, в итоге в каждой таблице будет только 1 первичный ключ).

3 форма : 2я форма + в каждой таблице отсутствуют неключевые столбцы, которые зависят друг от друга. если изменить значение в таком столбце, необходимо изменить и в сопряженных.
Как привести: так же как и 2ю, разделив по зависимым столбцам и сделав их первичными ключами.

Буду благодарен за комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 1НФ = Отношение -> 4 фундаментальных свойства.
2. 2НФ = 1НФ + нет неключевых атрибутов, зависящих от части ключа.
3. 3НФ = 2НФ + нет взаимозависимых неключевых атрибутов.

Comment: Ну вроде прав. не понимаю свойство : Нет упорядочивания. Что это значит?

Comment: Ни строки, ни атрибуты порядка не имеют.
Т.е. отношение = множество {имя атрибута, имя домена},
Кортежи = множество.